# What is a typical transfer rate for a Time Machine backup over FireWire?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, backup, time-machine

I am doing a TM backup for the first time to a portable disk from my macbook Pro(mid 2010) over a firewire connection (both ends).
The disk only contained a folder of around 20GB of manually backed up stuff before I decided to TM to it (left the folder). Now it's only done exactly 580MB in 30 mins (around 19.33Mb/min) is this normal?

Comment: No, that's not normal. Even over USB 2.0 (which is about 30% slower than FireWire), that should have taken about a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that the disk wasn't empty. Formatting the disk and starting again solved the problem.